# d3.js filter null values in nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, nested

I'm making a variety of charts for financial information – line, bar and pie, for example. The data comes from the client as .csv with some null values represented by hyphens. The format the data comes to me in is not something I can change. Here's an example:

```
    Month,Actual,Forecast,Budget
    Jul-14,200000,-,74073.86651
    Aug-14,198426.57,-,155530.2499
    Sep-14,290681.62,-,220881.4631
    Oct-14,362974.9,-,314506.6437
    Nov-14,397662.09,-,382407.67
    Dec-14,512434.27,-,442192.1932
    Jan-15,511470.25,511470.25,495847.6137
    Feb-15,-,536472.5467,520849.9105
    Mar-15,-,612579.9047,596957.2684
    Apr-15,-,680936.5086,465313.8723
    May-15,-,755526.7173,739904.081
    Jun-15,-,811512.772,895890.1357
```

I've been nesting the data using the following code and it works fine, except that the null values are causing me all sorts of problems.

```
    d3.csv("data/net.csv", function(error, data) {
      var headers = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(head) {
      return head != "Month";
    });

            data.forEach(function(d) {
              d.month = parseDate(d.Month);
    });

      var categories = headers.map(function(name) { 

        return {
          name: name, 
          values: data.map(function(d) { 
            return {
              date: d.month, 
              rate: +(d[name]),
              };
          }),
        };

      });
```

There's no problem when I'm defining a line because I can use .defined, but for appending circles on datapoints or rectangles on bar charts, it results in NaNs which break the visualisation.

Ideally, I'd like to have the nested data not include the null datapoints, rather than try to deal with the shapes after it's rendered. That is, from the above data I'd like the 'actual' and 'forecast' arrays to only have six objects, while the 'budget' array has 12. I'll also need to keep the index values.

Is there a way to filter the nesting process to exclude the null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a filter to remove all NaN elements before you do nesting like this:

```
 return {
              name: name,
              values: data.filter(function(k){return !isNaN(+k[name]);}).map(function(d) {
                return {
                  date: d.month,
                  rate: +(d[name]),
                };
              }),
            };
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XsMB3fwzsYeSGYIc5z4k?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Cyril,
Many thanks, it filters fine but doesn't keep the index values. I suspect that may not be possible.